# jQuery after selecting from a dropdown remove the same line from other dropdowns on the page

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to remove items from all dropdowns, except from the one where I choose from?

I have auto-generated dropdowns from my PHP code which makes a dropdown for every participant. The purpose of the dropdown is to give every participant a number to see who's the strongest (1) and the weakest (4 for example, depends on the amount of participants).

Now we've got the following;

> John -- dropdown from 1 to 4 here --
>
> Jeniffer -- dropdown from 1 to 4 here --
>
> Lloyd -- dropdown from 1 to 4 here --
>
> Julian -- dropdown from 1 to 4 here --

My goal is that when I select "1" from John's dropdown, that "1" disappears from the other people their dropdowns (so just 2, 3 and 4 are the remaining options).

Thanks

Comment: by saying dropdown you mean `<select>` with `<options>`'s ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. A select with option items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the element the event was triggered on. Something like:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('select').not(this).children('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove();
});
```

Best if you give the `select` elements their own class.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8QCZ/)

But you would also have to make sure to add an option again if the user changes his selection. In the worst case, if all options are set by the user, the user cannot change is selection anymore as there is nothing to select from. Consider this scenario.

Comment: @Roel instead of removing, maybe try disabling and enabling. in case they change their pick.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to not totally remove the item from the dropdown? I could add a disabled attribute, but how to enable it again after choosing a different item?

Answer (score 0):

if it is a `select` with `options`:

```
$('option').click(function(){
    $('option:contains(' + $(this).html() +')').not(this).remove();
});
```